# Is there a way to create sunburst/pie charts with histograms on the outermost layer?

Tags: python, r, graph, charts, graphics

I have a dataframe containing spatial data about the distribution of certain immune cells in tumors and I'm interested in displaying their distribution in a novel way. In essence I want to make a type of sunburst chart where the outermost layer is a histogram, roughly like this example below.

[image: Example]

At the moment, I was planning on trying to superimpose a radial histogram on top of a Sunburst chart, but I wanted to know if there was an existing function that could work.

Edit: below is the dataframe I've been working with

```
structure(list(slide = c("LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", 
"LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", 
"LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", 
"LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", 
"LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", 
"LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", 
"LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095", "LU095"
), stroma_bins = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), levels = c("0-10% Stroma", 
"10-20% Stroma", "20-30% Stroma", "30-40% Stroma", "40-50% Stroma", 
"50-60% Stroma", "60-70% Stroma", "70-80% Stroma", "80-90% Stroma", 
"90-100% Stroma"), class = "factor"), cd8_percent_bins = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), levels = c("0-2% CD8+ Cells", 
"2-4% CD8+ Cells", "4-6% CD8+ Cells", "6-8% CD8+ Cells", "8-10% CD8+ Cells", 
"10-15% CD8+ Cells", "15-20% CD8+ Cells", ">20% CD8+ Cells"), class = "factor"), 
    Freq = c(8L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 15L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 15L, 
    4L, 3L, 2L, 12L, 15L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 16L, 12L, 8L, 8L, 
    4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 14L, 4L, 17L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 5L, 2L, 51L, 18L, 
    24L, 24L, 17L, 32L, 21L, 11L)), row.names = c(NA, -46L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: package {circlize} probably covers this: https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize_book/book/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do this directly in ggplot.

First we reshape your data for plotting:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(geomtextpath)
library(colorspace)

plot_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(bar_pos = as.numeric(factor(cd8_percent_bins))) %>%
  group_by(stroma_bins) %>%
  mutate(max_bar = max(bar_pos)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  nest(data = -c(stroma_bins, max_bar)) %>%
  mutate(max_bar = cumsum(lag(max_bar, default = 0))) %>%
  unnest(cols = everything()) %>%
  mutate(bar_pos = max_bar + bar_pos + as.numeric(factor(stroma_bins)))
```

And the plotting code could be something like:

```r
ggplot(plot_df, aes(bar_pos, Freq, fill = stroma_bins, color = stroma_bins)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.6, color = NA) +
  geom_rect(data = . %>% group_by(stroma_bins) %>% 
              summarize(xmin = min(bar_pos) - 1, ymin = -0.5 * max(df$Freq),
                        xmax = max(bar_pos) + 1, ymax = -5, bar_pos = 1,
                        Freq = 1),
            aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, 
                fill = after_scale(darken(color, 0.25)))) +
  geom_textpath(data = . %>% group_by(stroma_bins) %>% 
                  summarize(Freq = -0.25 * max(df$Freq) - 2.5, 
                            bar_pos = mean(bar_pos)), angle = 90,
                aes(label = sub("-", "\u2013", sub(" Stroma", "", stroma_bins)), 
                    group = stroma_bins), color = "white") + 
  geom_textpath(aes(y = -2.5, label = sub("-", "\u2013",
                                          sub("% CD8\\+ Cells", "", 
                                              cd8_percent_bins)),
                    group = seq_along(cd8_percent_bins)), size = 2,
                color = "black") +
  annotate("text", x = 1, y = -max(df$Freq), label = "Stroma bin", size = 10, 
           color = "gray30") +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = "none") +
  scale_color_discrete(guide = "none") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-max(df$Freq), max(df$Freq) + 1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),
                     lim = c(1, nrow(df) + length(unique(df$stroma_bins)) + 2))+
  coord_polar() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(-100, -100, -100, -100))
```

[image]

Comment: That looks pretty perfect! Is there a way to make the size of each Var in the plot dependent on a vector? Also, I ran into the following error while running the above code: 


Error in `geom_col()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `compute_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics are not valid data columns.
✖ The following aesthetics are invalid:
✖ `y = n`
ℹ Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add `after_stat()`?

Comment: @fgootkind the above example only works on the data frame I created (you didn't supply any data in the question, so I had to create some). It would need tweaked to make it applicable to your own data. If you're stuck doing that, could you perhaps post your actual data in the question (if your data is called `df` then copy/paste the output from `dput(df)` into your question. Or provide a link to the data. Thanks.

Comment: The I used the dataframe you created, that was what produced the error. Maybe it's some quirk of my R environment. I posted the output of the dput funciton in the question above.

Comment: @fgootkind see my update. This should work with your own data in a fresh R session as long as your data is called `df` and you have the necessary packages.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I realize this is late, but would it be possible to introduce a secondary set of colors for the bar plot only? I have a color gradient in place for the rectangular plot using the following function `colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("cyan", "#f3be47"))`, `stroma_gradient <- colfunc(10)`, with stroma_gradient being used in the geom_rect function. Basically, I want two color gradients for each level of the chart that are more or less independent of each other.

Comment: Just wanted to reach out again. I've been having some trouble with the chart when it's applied to other samples, mainly with the 90-100% bin of the geom_rect() part of the chart disappearing. Do you have any idea why this might be happening?